# No carga css ni javascript de resources

Tags: css, hibernate, spring-mvc

Trabajo con Spring MVC, hice lo de WebConfig y probé colocando un archivo css y cargandolo desde una pagina .jsp y los estilos, nada que ver, no funcionan.

WebConfig.class

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc 
@ComponentScan 
@EnableTransactionManagement 
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que cargo en el `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='resources/style.css'/>" />
```

Probé colocando un "/" antes del resources pero tampoco funciona. También probé creando carpetas dentro de resources y modificando el `href` y nada tampoco.

y así está conformado mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trabajo con Spring MVC, JPA con Hibernate.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esta linea:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/style.css">
```

Y dentro del web.xml

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

Comment: Si es algo que también intenté pero no me funciona. :c

Comment: Más allá de si a OP le funciona o no, estaría bueno que expliques que hace tu código, para que tanto OP como otras personas que aparezcan en el futuro entiendan que hace tu código.